# Liferay hide specific role from specific users

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-6, roles

I do have some unique requirements where I want to hide a role to be selected from specific role users.

For example I have a role name admin, department 1, department 2 and department 3.
As a admin I should be able to see only department 1, department 2 and department 3 for role management in my portal.

But if I define permission for admin that he/she can manage roles. 
Admin user is able to see all the roles which are available OOTB in Liferay.

Can anyone help me with the configurations?

Comment: Do you want to remove roles from list for which admin role user don't have any permissions[not having any action to perform]?

Answer (score 0):

The administrator role is by Liferay outside of permission concept, so the admin can manage all other roles. 
You can create another role like Department-Role-Admin and put them necessary permissions.